# Vlc - package dependencies cannot be resolved

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-center, ppa, vlc

I tried to install Vlc 2.2 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as it not available on Ubuntu Software Centre using following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc
```

But it showed errors:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 3.0.0~~git20150319+r59816+33~ubuntu14.04.1) but 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 is to be installed
   Depends: libavcodec55 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not installable or
            libavcodec-extra-55 (>= 6:10~~git20131218.b3189af~ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not installable
   Depends: libavutil53 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not installable
   Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 3.0.0~~git20150319+r59816+33~ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
   Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 3.0.0~~git20150319+r59816+33~ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
   Breaks: vlc-nox (< 2.2.0~pre2-2~) but 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 is to be installed
vlc-nox : Depends: libvlccore7 (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: libdvdcss2 but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

now even if I try to install it using Ubuntu Software Centre it shows me error that package dependencies cannot be resolved.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

VLC is there in the Ubuntu Repos as well. You can install it after enabling universe Repo. This should be automatically enabled for you when you Install Ubuntu and select install 3rd party software and install Updates while Installing.

If you missed it during Install you can enble unniverse repository by Opening Software and Sources and select the repositories as shown in the picture.

[image: Enabling Universe and Multiverse Repos]

After hiting close you get option to reload the Cache.

[image: Reload Software cache]

Once that is done you should see VLC in software Center or you may install it via command line.

There is no need for adding any third party repo unless you can't find what you want in the official repo or you want the latest and greatest.

PPA's can sometimes break your system because of library mismatch. Alway USE PPA's with caution.

Comment: OP wants to install VLC 2.2. It is not in Ubuntu repos.

Comment: This is not helping for me. How can it work if my system is trying to install Vlc 2.2 which is not there in Ubuntu

Comment: @LINUXLOVER if there is a problem with the Third Party Repository, then contact with the maintainer of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you for your help and support, but I found a answer to this. I have removed the repository and now everything is running fine.

Comment: Were you able to Install VLC2.2 Just curious to understand if your VLC Installation is fine !!