# How can I safely revert libglapi-mesa version?

Tags: apt

Currently I [cannot install some software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/665806/cannot-install-vlc-on-15-04-dependencies-cannot-be-resolved).

sudo `apt-get install vlc` gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 vlc : Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libgles1
       Depends: libgles2-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libgles2
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Trying to install libgles via [Syanptic](http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/) gives

[image]

Which when checking in Syanptic is clear:

[image]

Trying to force a specific version back down to 10.5.2 seems to indicate it's going to install a lot of my things which I have configured nicely:

[image]

Obviously I don't want to do this, but I would like to be able to use this PC again.

They don't appear in the to be installed list:

[image]

`grep -r 'ricotz' /etc/apt/` gives:

```
grep: /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg: Permission denied
```

`sudo grep -r 'ricotz' /etc/apt/` gives no output

`sudo apt-cache policy libglapi-mesa` gives:

```
libglapi-mesa:
  Installed: 10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~utopic
  Candidate: 10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~utopic
  Version table:
 *** 10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~utopic 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     10.5.2-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
```

`sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa=10.5.2-0ubuntu1` gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 monodoc-browser : Depends: libwebkit1.1-cil (>= 0.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

`sudo apt-cache policy libwebkit1.1.cil` gives:

```
libwebkit1.1-cil:
  Installed: 0.3-6
  Candidate: 0.3-6
  Version table:
 *** 0.3-6 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Steps from A.B.'s answer:

```
nikolai@dante:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
[sudo] password for nikolai: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
nikolai@dante:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
nikolai@dante:~$ sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesi=10.5.2-0ubuntu1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libglapi-mesi
nikolai@dante:~$ sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa=10.5.2-0ubuntu1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 monodoc-browser : Depends: libwebkit1.1-cil (>= 0.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `grep -r 'ricotz' /etc/apt/`

Comment: And the output of `apt-cache policy libglapi-mesa`

Comment: Ok, seems to be a bigger job. Start again with my answer, I have added a step. Give me a ping with @A.B.

Comment: Have you `aptitude` installed?

Comment: @A.B. I don't. I can try and install it. I've added the out put from your answer. Many thanks.

Comment: Check the installation of aptitude. If an installation isn't possible, we can use synaptic.

Comment: @a.B. `aptitude` has installed fine. After my sons bedtime, i'll follow your edit. Many thanks.

Comment: =) Ok, but first, read my answer again and try if you can achieve something.

Comment: @A.B. I've done that, and as I feared it's removed pretty much everything I use on this box. I've managed to `sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa=10.5.2-0ubuntu1` what are my next steps to be able to build this system back up (i.e. put my software back) and make sure it doesn't get in a mess again?

Comment: What do you mean by that "it's removed pretty much everything"? Your desktop environment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27577/discussion-between-a-b-and-nikolaidante).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution could be

> Downgrade the package `libglapi-mesa` via
>
> ```
>     sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa=10.5.2-0ubuntu1
> ```
>
> You have installed version
>   `10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~utopic` from a PAA, that's
>   not longer exist in your system or manually via `dpkg -i` or an other
>   tool.

But your system is pretty broken.

**Work in progress...**

In this case, ***there is no stubborn sequence of steps***. You have to decide and act on their own. I can give you advice only.

Currently we have only <kbd>Synaptic Package Manager</kbd>, therefore use it:

- Disable unnecessary PPAs and other repositories. You can re-add them later.

  [image]

  Use <kbd>Reload</kbd>

  [image]
- All packages in the category <kbd>Installed (local or obsolete)</kbd> should be removed or downgraded

  First try a downgrade. If that's not possible, remove the package. Do this step by step, not all at once. After each removal, check the category <kbd>Installed (auto removable)</kbd> and remove the packages also. Be in mind, packages can be re-installed but you should not remove the kernel ;)

  From time to time it's necessary to restart Synaptic. But this assertion comes from my experience and does not have to be true.

  [image]
- Remove packages that can be re-installed

---

Here are some points from the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27577/discussion-between-a-b-and-nikolaidante@)

- Before you restart your system check

  - Is your desktop is still installed?

    ```
    apt-cache policy unity
    ```
  - Is your network manager is installed?

    ```
    apt-cache policy network-manager
    ```
  - Is your graphic installed

    ```
    nvidia-settings --version
    ```

Be in mind and helpful links

- [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)
- [What's a good back-up strategy for 1 desktop PC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)
- [How do I find the reverse dependency of a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13296/how-do-i-find-the-reverse-dependency-of-a-package/13297#13297)

Comment: I've accepted your answer, but theres a few extra steps from the chat that could do with being added. Many thanks :)

Comment: I'll read the chat and make the modifications a little bit later today.