# Problem installing vlc - unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, vlc

**Update : I was able to install it with aptitude, which automatically fixed the version of a bunch of packages. However, some ricotz packages are still making problems in other areas.**

I tried to install vlc on a rather fresh installation of ubuntu 16.10 but I'm getting this error :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libgles1
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I tried

```
sudo apt-get install libgles1-mesa
```

Which in turn gives me

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgles1-mesa : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 12.0.3-1ubuntu2) but 12.1~git20161011.fc8b358b-0ubuntu0ricotz is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried

```
sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa=12.0.3-1ubuntu2
```

as well, but that basically just tells me that no component is going to be installed.

Comment: Ricotz, isn't that the name of a PPA? Did you install the Gnome testing PPA? That may be the cause of the problem. (You were warned ;-)

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/667416/how-can-i-safely-revert-libglapi-mesa-version)?

Comment: @Jos I barely installed anything, definitely no Gnome testing PPA.

Comment: @Jos The question doesn't really help me unfortunately. I was able to find the package libglapi-mesa in synaptic and there are indeed 2 available versions. However, if I try to force the version to 12.0.3, synaptic tells me that tons of packages would have to be removed (including my graphics driver, libre office, etc)

Comment: Apologies for insisting, but doesn't the word `ricotz` appear anywhere in `/etc/apt/sources.d` or `/etc/apt/sources.d.list`? If so, then you'd better remove that source. If not, then some package is dependent on a library provided by an PPA, which is very, very unusual.

Comment: The word is definitely not in there. I'm not sure what could have required this specific version... I basically installed my graphics driver, gnome-shell and a few applications, that's it.

Comment: You used this ppa, https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa Your best bet is to install  ppa-purge &  make sure the ppa is still enabled. Then run ppa-purge as noted in the ppa page's  description